# Techniques to redimension an array in Java : is "nullifying" the array bad?

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic

I'm learning Java and surprisingly I found out that Java arrays are not dynamic - even though its cousing languages have dynamic arrays.

So I came out with ideas to kind of imitate a dynamic array in java on my own.

One thought I had was to copy the original array references to a temporary array, then turn the original array to null, re-set its index to a bigger value and then finally re-copy the values from the temporary array.

Example.:

```
if(numberOfEntries == array.length){
        Type[] temp = new Type[numberOfEntries];
        for(int x=0; x < numberOfEntries; x++){
            temp[x] = array[x];
        }
        array = null;
        array = new Type[numberOfEntries+1];
        for(int x=0; x < numberOfEntries; x++){
            array[x] = temp[x];
        }
```

I know that this can result in data loss if the process is interrupted, but aside from that, is this a bad idea? What are my options?

Thanks!

Comment: Use an ArrayList or Arrays.copyOf().

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you can use ArrayList. It matters because you are replacing Array objects with different array objects.

Comment: Omg. So many good answers. Its hard to choose the best! I think I'll leave the coice to the public or wait for a killing answer. Java has a realy good comunity!

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is in the right ballpark. But for a task that you propose you should never implement your own version, unless it is for academic purposes and fun.

What you propose is roughly implemented by the [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class. 
This has an internal array and a size 'counter'. The internal array is filled when items are added. When the internal array is full all elements are copied to a bigger array. The internal array is never released to the user of the class (to make sure it's state is always valid).

In your example code, because an array is a pointer, you don't really need the temp array. Just create a new one, copy all elements and save the pointer to it as your array.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29). Changing the size of the array by 1 is likely to be very inefficient. Depending on your use case, you might want to increase the array size by double, and similarly halve the array when it's only a quarter full.

ArrayList is convenient, but once it's full, it takes linear time to add an element. You can achieve something similar to resizing with the `ensureCapacity()` method. I'd recommend becoming more familiar with Java's Collections framework so you can make the best decisions in future by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not dynamic their size can't change dynamically and right now you aren't changing the same object, you are replacing smaller size object with larger size object

```
     int[5] Arr = new int[5] ; // Create an array of size 5
     Arr = new int[10] ;// you assigned the different objects. It is not the same object.
```

So, we can't change the size of the array dynamically. You can use ArrayList for the same.

But keep try !!!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at java.util.ArrayList which is dynamically, it is part of the Collections framework. Making the Array dynamically should be slower and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about time complexity , do you know how much time complexity you are increasing, Every time you are copying old array element to new array let you have 1 million element in array then think about copying time of element of one array to another array.

One more thing i want to tell you, ArrayList implementation used same logic except new length that you are using .

Comment: Yeah, I understand time complexity and I know that a increase by one will make it a mess of a time consuming application. It is just a theory - and now that people remembered me that an array is an object and that the variable points to it, the temporary array can be removed, halving the time complexity. Also, I didn't learn about ArrayList yet.